# Bind the media_src from the __metadata in an XML view

Tags: sapui5

I have a oData GW service returning a list of attachments and I am trying to render them in a UploadCollectionList on a XML view... The GW service has the media flag turned on and in the return call I have the **media_src** property on the **__metadata** structure on the return.

I can not figure out how in a XML view to reference it so I can bind the UploadCollectionList URL property to the **__metadata - media_src** property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was apparently overthinking this....

```
url : "{__metadata/media_src}"
```

works no problem...

Derek.